# How to manipulate mark up before or after React render

Tags: reactjs

I have an old javascript function/object that does something kind of like this

```
function convertToReadOnly()
{
    var readOnlyBlocks = $('.read-only');

    for(var c=0; c<readOnlyBlocks.length; c++)
    {

            var fields = $(readOnlyBlocks[c]).find('input[type="text"]');
            for(var d=0; fields.length; d++)
            {
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                $(p).html($(fields[d]).val());
                $(fields[d]).remove();
                $(readOnlyBlocks[c]).append(p);
                etc...
            }
            repeat for select, textarea, etc...

    }
}
```

I'm upgrading my application to use React.  My challenge is I'm not sure when I should fire this `convertToReadOnly()` function.  I tried putting my `convertToReadOnly()` function in the `componentDidUpdate()` of one of my react components.  But when I look in my error console, I see the message

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.6.3.0.1.0):
>   Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly
>   mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a 
>   when using tables, nesting tags like ,
>
> , or , or using
>   non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of
>   the element with React ID ``.

My question is what is the best way to do all this?  Should I be firing my `convertToReadOnly()` at another loadcycle opportunity?  Should I NOT manipulate the DOM with jquery?  If so, then how do I manipulate the react version of the dom?  Any other ideas?

**EDIT - Why am I even trying to do this?**

Before I upgraded to react, I found it very useful to rely on current and parent css class names to determine the edit privileges of current and child elements.  So for example, if a div has a class `access-denied`, then all child elements are removed.  If a div has a class `read-only`, then all child elements will be converted to their read only equivalents (which is not necessarily readonly="readonly", the elements might be converted to other html elements that can be styled in different ways).

I found this to be a much more maintainable approach then

- littering my view files with a bunch of if/else statement checks around every possible control

or

- creating a separate read-only view for each component

It is so much easier for any element to just inherit the access privileges of a parent element, and render itself accordingly.   Since I'm new to react, I can't seem to find a way to harmonize my approach with the react approach.  is it because my way of thinking is incompatible with react development philosophy?

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested creating a higher order component

https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775